# How can I delete an element completely from a WordPress plugin page?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have downloaded a WordPress plugin and in some of their pages, they show annoying adds and links to their site. I would like to delete this (worst case, hide it) from showing on the page.

When I click "Inspect Element" on Chrome I can see the element's name, but I cannot see the location on the server (unlike CSS where it gives you the location so you can easily change it).

How can I find the locations of these elements so I can delete it?

Comment: beware that doing this may violate the terms of the plugin. do they have a paid verson that removes advertising?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, I would double check the options in the plugin. There might be an obscure option in it to disable the adverts.
2. You can find the name of the element and add in the CSS

   ```
   .elementname
   {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
3. Download a copy of the plugin from your website and use a program like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.6.3.html) to search through the plugin folder (that you just downloaded) for the name of the element. And try remove it from the pages you find.